# addListener's sendResponse called from callback returns previous message

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webkit

In the beginning I thought that the problem is with `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` I was sending two messages. One for accessing `localstorage` and another one to get/read the file data, but nothing changed after I merged them in one `sendMessage` which means that the actual problem is `window.webkitRequestFileSystem()` it's returning the previous file instead of the current one.

Is there a better/faster way of storing something client side ? (I'm willing to try everything) ?

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "unlimitedStorage"
  ]
}
```

background.js

```
var theme = '';

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.method == "getTheme") {
      themes    = JSON.parse(localStorage["themes"]);
      themeName = "";
      for (var i = themes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(request.url.indexOf(themes[i]) !== -1) {
          themeName = themes[i];
        }
      };
      window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 0, readFromFileStorage.bind(window, themeName), errorHandler);

      sendResponse({data: theme});
    }
});

  function readFromFileStorage(filename, fs) {

    fs.root.getFile(filename, {}, function(fileEntry) {

      fileEntry.file(function(file) {
         var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onloadend = function(e) {
            theme = this.result;
          };

         reader.readAsText(file);
      }, errorHandler);
    }, errorHandler);
  }

    function errorHandler(e) {
      console.log('Error: ' + e.message);
    }
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: "getTheme", url: location.href}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

Comment: Once again: Don't use **chrome.extension.onMessage/sendMessage**. Use **chrome.runtime.\*** instead ! BTW, what is `files` is `file = files[i]` ? do you mean `themes[i]` ?

Comment: And what is `data` in the `background.js` snippet, line 7 ? It is a mess ! Please, post the actual code or an **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)**.

Comment: Hi, you actually can get the url in background.js trough Tab object.  And you can get localStorage from content script, trough chrome.storage.local for your extension's storage, or localStorage for the pages' storage.

Comment: @YoArgentino: What you mention is very true, but (for the most part) it is not what OP wants...

Comment: What do you mean by "it returns the previous file" ?

Comment: `themeName` is actually the name of the site. ex site1.com site2.com. when I visit `site1` the 1-st time i get an empty string, after a refresh i get the file I need. but if I go to `site2` I'm getting the data from `site1` and after an refresh I'm getting the correct data/file content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your question is not an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) it is hard to test it, but I think your problem is understanding of JS asynchronous nature.

So how your code will actually execute:

1. First `window.webkitRequestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, 0, successCallback, errorHandler);` will be executed
2. Then `sendResponse({data: theme});` will send the response with whatever is stored in `theme`
3. Then either `successCallback` either `errorHandler` will be called depending on file request success. If `successCallback` will be called then you'll have your `theme` variable filled with the value you want. But it will be to late as you already sent the response.

The next time you pass the message you will receive previous theme value (point 2) as your code will find new value only after you'll send the value.

A solution may be to call `sendResponse` inside of `successCallback` after you find your desired value (you'll have to pass `sendResponse` into `readFromFileStorage`). If you'll do so then you may consider to add `sendResponse` into `errorHandler` function just to be sure that your code will always get a valid response.

In case that you'll move the `sendResponse` into a callback then you have to return true from `addListener` function, otherwise on `addListener` return channel will be closed and response will not be sent.